# How can I print a particular list of text using gawk/grep ? for example I would like to print the names of all the colors present in txt file

Tags: linux, shell, grep, gawk

Just started learning Linux. Getting my hands dirty with grep and gawk.

Suppose I want to print all the available names in .txt file or for example I have text file that goes;

```
"blah blah blah blah blah

blah bhah blah blah blah

Joe

Allen

David

John

blah blah blah blah blah "
```

Now I would like to print all the names found in the text file only.
How would I go about doing it? What will my syntax be?

Comment: What does your input look like, exactly? Your output? What have you tried so far? Have you proof-read your question title? This is all not very clear to me.

Comment: Sorry about that. 
please check the question again, I made some changes to make things clearer.
I think ill be needing a gawk script but sadly I have no idea how to go about it.
thanks for the reply.

Comment: gawk '/Joe/{print $0}' Input.txt

The above simple command helps me print Joe but i am unable to add other names to the same single command. 
Also is there any other way to do it ?

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Having a file "names" with all the names you're looking for, one per line:

```
 Allen
 David
 Joe
 ...
```

Then search of any of those lines:

```
grep -f names thefiles
```

You might need to add the option -F (the lines in the file "names" are strings, and not regex-en) or option -w (the match must be a word, not part of word) as well, or the option -o (print only the match, instead of the line).